# call-process: How to output the progress bars to a buffer

Tags: call-process

In the following example using a terminal window (Ubuntu 20.04), the program `ocrmypdf` produces some progress bars while it is running and the last two (2) lines are printed when the program finishes.  Using the Emacs function `call-process` and the optional arguments of DESTINATION (`non-nil`) and DISPLAY (`non-nil`), only the last two (2) lines are output to the target buffer when the program finishes.  Is there a way to see progress bar output while the program is running when using the function `call-process`?

```
$ ocrmypdf input.pdf output.pdf
Scan: 100%|██████████████████████████████████| 11/11 [00:00<00:00, 229.81page/s]
OCR: 100%|████████████████████████████████| 11.0/11.0 [03:09<00:00, 17.26s/page]
JPEGs: 0image [00:00, ?image/s]
JBIG2: 100%|██████████████████████████████████| 11/11 [00:00<00:00, 11.61item/s]
INFO - Optimize ratio: 1.28 savings: 22.1%
INFO - Output file is a PDF/A-2B (as expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was that the progress bars were being sent to `stderr` and you were only seeing `stdout`, but `(elisp)Synchronous Processes` indicates that when `DESTINATION` is a buffer you would get both streams interspersed; so it doesn't sound like that's the specific issue.

Nevertheless, you could try using the `(REAL-BUFFER STDERR-FILE)` form of DESTINATION and see if you end up with anything in your error file.

(And/or `ocrmypdf ... 2>/dev/null` in your proper terminal.)

Another possibility is that `ocrmypdf` is detecting the dumb terminal and refraining from outputting any progress bars.  See whether it documents any behaviour regarding that.  You could then `let`-bind a `process-environment` to pretend you're offering a more capable `TERM` and see what happens.  (Or conversely, `env TERM=dumb ocrmypdf ...` in your proper terminal to see if the progress bars go away.)

If you *do* get it to output progress bars, you may then find yourself in need of a filter to handle that output (depending on what the process is sending).